# How split comma separated string into multiple rows in AWS redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Im trying to separate string values to multiple rows grouped by its id column.
Most of the answers i saw include some of this functions however they are not supported by aws redshift https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html

Assume i have a table like this

| id | order_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001,10005,10006 |
| 2 | 11000,12005 |

And i would like to have a result like this

| id | order_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 |
| 1 | 10005 |
| 1 | 10006 |
| 2 | 11000 |
| 2 | 12005 |

Comment: Have you looked at SPLIT_PART? That allows you to specify a delimiter that will chunk your string into individual columns. You can use that in a subquery to build your new table or insert to the existing one.

Comment: Write business logic to perform this task using a programming languages of your choice

Comment: See the answer to another SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73647600/6206

Answer (score 1):

A few concepts to have in mind.  First is the recursive CTE which can be used to create number values for each position in the order_id string.  Second is json functions which can split the string into parts based on commas.

A full test case with expanded input data:

```
create table test (id int,  order_id varchar(256));

insert into test values 
(1, '10001,10005,10006'),
(2, '11000,12005'),
(3, '10001,10005,10006,21000,22005'),
(4, '21000,22005,10001,10005,10006,11000,12005,10001,10005,10006,21000,22005')
;


with recursive numbers(n) as (
  select 0 as n
  union all
  select n + 1 
  from numbers n
  where n < (select max(length(order_id) - length(replace(order_id, ',',''))) from test)
),
input as (
  select id, order_id, 
  length(order_id) - length(replace(order_id, ',','')) no_of_elements --counts the number of commas in the string
  from test
)
select id, json_extract_array_element_text('['||order_id||']', n.n) as order_id
from input t
join numbers n
on n.n <= t.no_of_elements
order by id, order_id
;
```