# Check if a date is between any of N pairs of dates

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table in Redshift consisting of ~ 5 Million rows. The Period Starts and Ends column are varchars that could have any number of pairs of dates, that together represent a date range, so the first entry in Period_Starts matches with the first entry in Period_Ends to make a date range. For example, in the first row, the date ranges are (2020-03-02 - 2021-02-06) and (2021-02-07 - 2022-01-01).

| Date | Cluster | Period_Starts | Period_Ends |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 2020-03-02, 2021-02-07 | 2021-02-06, 2022-01-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2 | 2021-02-09 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2021-01-01 | 3 | 2019-02-03, 2019-09-10, 2020-01-01 | 2019-09-09, 2019-12-31, 2021-01-1 |

I am trying to create a function which checks if the Date column is within any of these ranges, and returns the period if a match is found.

For example, passing the first row into the function should return something like "2020-03-02:2021-02-06".

I have come up with this using a python UDF, but it runs quite slowly, and I am wondering if there is a way to just use SQL to do it more efficiently.

```
create function f_check_period(date_to_check Date, starts varchar, ends varchar)
  returns varchar
stable
as $$
  import datetime
  starts_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d") for x in starts.split(",")]
  ends_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d") for x in ends.split(",")]
  
  for i in range(0,len(starts_list)):
      if starts_list[i] <= date_to_check <= ends_list[i]:
          return starts_list[i] + ":" + ends_list[i]

$$ language plpythonu;
```

Comment: Sorry for me asking this - but what about a decent database design with a master-child relationship for those periods instead of mangling those strings......

Comment: Your *real* problem is your schema. Fix that and you won't need an answer to this question.

Comment: I do not have control over the schema, it is loaded in from a transactional db that is managed by somebody else, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a simple JOIN?  You will need to break the period_start and period_end rows of your range table into different rows.   Join this with your table ON "date" between date_min and date_max.  Then just pick off which cluster the row is in.

Breaking this out will give you 6 rows in your example periods table.  If things are really this simple it can be done by hand or with SQL.  Several examples of this are on SO. Like: [How split comma separated string into multiple rows in AWS redshift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73666277/how-split-comma-separated-string-into-multiple-rows-in-aws-redshift/73674102#73674102)

The query will simply be something like:

```
select t.*, r.cluster
from <table> t
join <ranges> r
on t."date" between r.period_start and r.period_end;
```