# Redshift how to split a stringified array into separate parts

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Say I have a varchar column let's say `religions` that looks like this: `["Christianity", "Buddhism", "Judaism"]` (yes it has a bracket in the string) and I want the string (not array) split into multiple rows like `"Christianity", "Buddhism", "Judaism"` so it can be used in a `WHERE` clause.

Eventually I want to use the results of the query in a where clause like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM religions
WHERE name in 
    (
        <this subquery>
    )
```

How can one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [JSON_PARSE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_PARSE.html) to convert the varchar string into an array. Then you can use the strategy described in [Convert varchar array to rows in redshift - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73636461/convert-varchar-array-to-rows-in-redshift/73647600#73647600) to convert the array to separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

1. Create a temporary table with sequence of numbers
2. Using the sequence and `split_part` function available in redshift, you can split the values based on the numbers generated in the temporary table by doing a cross join.
3. To replace the double quote and square brackets, you can use the `regexp_replace` function in Redshift.

```
create temp table seq as
with recursive numbers(NUMBER) as
(
select 1 UNION ALL
select NUMBER + 1 from numbers where NUMBER < 28
)
select * from numbers;

select regexp_replace(split_part(val,',',seq.number),'[]["]','') as value
from
(select '["christianity","Buddhism","Judaism"]' as val) -- You can select the actual column from the table here.
cross join
seq
where seq.number <= regexp_count(val,'[,]')+1;
```